# How to create a schema to add several array into object Node/mongo db using post

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

this is the schema that I have now but I need to add more array as number 2, 3, 4

```
> const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
>     navigation: {
>         1: [
>             
>             subSchema
>         ]
>     }  })
```

example:

```
> {
>     "navigation": {
>         "1": [test]
>         "2":[test2] }
> }
```

//post api

```
const post = new Post({
        navigation: req.body.navigation
    });
    response = {
        message: 'success',
        uuid: req.body.uuid
    }
    try {
        const savedPost = await post.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to create a schema with an empty object like:

Schema

```
const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    navigation: {}  
})
```

so you can add multiple elements. But your data completely depends on what you are sending in your API request.